# Booting impossible cause GRUB rescue won't let me

Tags: 12.04, boot, lubuntu, grubrescue

I created two bootable USB: ***Lubuntu 12.10*** and ***Ubuntu 12.04*** from my windows machine.

**SCENE 1**

I installed **Ubuntu 12.04**, everything is fine. A popup window appears that says something like *"I have successfully installed the operating system and a reboot is required."* I am about to click the reboot now button, when the electricity went off (No laptop battery)! Now I boot back, and found out that my Ubuntu will only normally boot if the USB is plugged in, if I removed it, only the blinking insert cursor will just be there for me.

**SCENE 2**

With my crazy mind, I thought of installing the **Lubuntu 12.04** so it will forget memories of **Ubuntu 12.04**. I inserted the USB and there goes the installation. All went well, I played with Lubuntu for a couple of hours. But then, my consciousness reminds me : *I want my Ubuntu back.*

**SCENE 3**

Once more, I inserted the **Ubuntu 12.04**. I miss the violets, so I expected that much I'll see it. But then, I am a failure. Here is this shitty GRUB rescue that keeps telling me error blah, blah.

**SCENE 4**

Nowhere to go, booted back to **Lubuntu 12.10**. Type my story here and hoping someone will lead me back to my home... Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the compliment. No, I'm not. But I want to be a director. Any idea about my problem anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in windows installer.

Easy way -

1. Reinstall ubuntu by replacing lubuntu.
2. Still facing same issue? Boot up with live ubuntu disk and use [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) tool. Click on "Recommended repair ". At end it will give a url, note that down. If these step doesn't fix the issue, post that link here.

Advance Option : If you are know how to customize partition.

Install ubuntu, while installing there will be prompt saying "Replace current ubuntu", "Reinstall Ubuntu" and `Something Else`

Choose "something else"

Then do the routine assignment of partition mapping. (If you don't what I am saying stick to Easy option)

**Make sure `boot-loader` location is your hard disk not usb disk. (Hard disk most probably will be marked as `sda` where as usb as `sdb`)**

Comment: Thanks a friend in need. Easy way 1 is my choice, however it wont let me install my Ubuntu from my USB. Also, I don't have the Windows anymore, right now my laptop is only having Lubuntu.

Comment: My friend here is the pastebin link http://paste.ubuntu.com/1570148/